# Max value from the nodes of a XML file in php

Tags: xml, max

I would like to be able to retrieve the max value from a the nodes of a `XML` file in php. In my limited knowledge about php and `XML` files I can't understand why this isn't working:

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $output) {
  if ($output->VALUE>0) {
    echo 'max($output->VALUE)';
  }
}
```

A simplified version of my XML-file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PROFILES xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SECTION>
    <MODE>ON</MODE>
    <VALUE>5</VALUE>
    <GAMES>10</GAMES>
  </SECTION>
  <SECTION>
    <MODE>ON</MODE>
    <VALUE>7</VALUE>
    <GAMES>8</GAMES>
  </SECTION>
  <SECTION>
    <MODE>ON</MODE>
    <VALUE>3</VALUE>
    <GAMES>4</GAMES>
  </SECTION>
</PROFILES>
```

The max value should be retrieved among:

- 5
- 7
- 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the XML in a string called `$xmlstr`, this works:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$values = [];
foreach ($xml->SECTION as $section) {
    array_push($values, intval($section->VALUE));
}
echo max($values);
```

Comment: Hi fafl. I can't get it to work. I'm using simplexml_load_file. Is that the problem?

Comment: That should work, `simplexml_load_file` returns a SimpleXMLElement. Check out this fiddle: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c8cd7cda8dff569d230b7db64cf056ecd5969c4